# Trackback controls Alpha value for color

Tags: c#, winforms, colors, alpha, trackbar

I have a textbox which I'm using its backcolor as a color preview, and a trackbar which controls the alpha of that color. I'm using the following code:

```
private void trackAlpha_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    colorPreview.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(trackAlpha.Value, colorDialog.Color.R, colorDialog.Color.G, colorDialog.Color.B);
}
```

Turns out that scrolling the alpha will have no effect on the preview whatsoever.

Any ideas on why this could be happening?

Comment: Is this WinForms, or WPF, or something else?

Comment: It's a form. Pardon me, should have included that.

Comment: I added the tag for you.

Comment: Does winforms support transparency?

Comment: It does, I used it in another application of mine that has the same function - change the transparency of the backcolor of a textbox. I copied and pasted this exact code in this new project and changed the needed stuff, still no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WinForms `Control`s do support an alpha channel, but not by default.  For the control that you want to have a translucent back color, you must call the [`SetStyle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.setstyle.aspx) method:

```
this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor, true);
```

The method is protected, so you'll have to inherit from the control you want and call it in the constructor or something.  This control will be whatever `colorPreview` is referring to.

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, but should I use it in the `public Form1()` part and just use the ColorFromArgb method normally in the trackbar slide section?

Comment: @P1CUnrelated See my edit: This control will be whatever `colorPreview` is referring to.

Comment: Well, again, pardon my ignorance. I put the code you showed in the `public Form1()` part of the code, only, as I see no connection between it and `colorPreview`. Again, sorry, I'd really appreciate a second explanation, though.

Comment: I assume `colorPreview` refers to a control.  Whatever the type of that control, you'll need to create your own type that inherits from it, and calls `SetStyle` in that control's constructor.

Comment: Yes, it indeed is. It's a textbox named `colorPreview` whose backcolor I'm trying to change. I put the snippet you showed me in the trackbar that is supposed to change the textbox transparency, still no success. Sorry for making you explain me all of this, I really don't know what's going on anymore.

Comment: Make a child class of `TextBox` that calls `SetStyle` in the constructor, and then change `colorPreview` to be an instance of that type rather than `TextBox`.